# iText 7.0.2 adding fixed size table to document text not wrapping and somethimes goes into infinite loop

Tags: java-8, itext, itext7

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.List;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.border.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.border.SolidBorder;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;

public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
    try
    {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("output1.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);   
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        document.setLeftMargin(30);
        document.setRightMargin(30);

        final Table myTable = new Table(new float[]
                { 30, 65, 120, 180, 100, 25 });// { 30, 65, 150, 180, 100, 25 }); works.
        setTableProperties(myTable, pdfDocument, 70, 7, "italic", Color.BLACK);
        myTable.setFixedLayout();

        final PdfFont font = getPdfFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
        myTable.setFont(font).setFontSize(7).setItalic().setFontColor(Color.WHITE);

        //*** Start - Added Header*****
        //BLOCK THIS TO See Issue 1 below, UNBLOCK Causes issue 2 and it hangs
        createTableHeader(myTable);
        //*** End - Added Header *****

        //*** Start Add Data ****
        equipmentTableData(myTable, "NUMITEMS", false, TextAlignment.CENTER);
        equipmentTableData(myTable, "CONDENSADORCONDENSAD", false, TextAlignment.CENTER); 

        // MATNUMBERUCACHBMPVAIRD4EFANFUC (com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer - Element does not fit current area)
        // MATNUMBERUCACHB-PVAIRD4EFANFUC (Works ok.. it wraps at '-')
        // MATNUMBERUCACH1MPVAIRD4EFANFUC (added '1' in middle Works ok.. 'MATNUMBERUCACH1MPVAIRD4EF' 'ANFUC')
        equipmentTableData(myTable, "MATNUMBERUCACHBMPVAIRD4EFANFUC", false, TextAlignment.CENTER);
        equipmentTableData(myTable, "MATERIALDESCRIPTIONDOPKSOPKDKJSLIOULOISOOPWOSKLISL", false, TextAlignment.CENTER);
        equipmentTableData(myTable, "DETAILS", false, TextAlignment.CENTER);
        equipmentTableData(myTable, "QTY", false, TextAlignment.CENTER);
        //*** End Add Data ****

        document.add(myTable); // Goes in infinite loop if createTableHeader is enabled above, and i can see pdf file size growing

        document.close(); 

    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Error " + e);
    }
}

private static Table createTableHeader(final Table myTable)
{
    Cell customCell;
    List listforPrepared;
    listforPrepared = new List().setSymbolIndent(0).setListSymbol(" ");
    listforPrepared.add("Line");
    listforPrepared.add("Item");

    customCell = new Cell(1, 1).add(listforPrepared).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY).setFontColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    myTable.addHeaderCell(customCell);

    listforPrepared = new List().setSymbolIndent(0).setListSymbol(" ");
    listforPrepared.add("Tag:");
    customCell = new Cell(1, 1).add(listforPrepared).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY).setFontColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    myTable.addHeaderCell(customCell);

    listforPrepared = new List().setSymbolIndent(0).setListSymbol(" ");
    listforPrepared.add("Material");
    listforPrepared.add("Number");
    customCell = new Cell(1, 1).add(listforPrepared).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY).setFontColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    myTable.addHeaderCell(customCell);

    listforPrepared = new List().setSymbolIndent(0).setListSymbol(" ");
    listforPrepared.add("Description");
    customCell = new Cell(1, 1).add(listforPrepared).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY).setFontColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    myTable.addHeaderCell(customCell);

    listforPrepared = new List().setSymbolIndent(0).setListSymbol(" ");
    listforPrepared.add("Detail");
    customCell = new Cell(1, 1).add(listforPrepared).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY).setFontColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    myTable.addHeaderCell(customCell);

    listforPrepared = new List().setSymbolIndent(0).setListSymbol(" ");
    listforPrepared.add("QTY");
    customCell = new Cell(1, 1).add(listforPrepared).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY).setFontColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    myTable.addHeaderCell(customCell);

    return myTable;

}

private static  Table equipmentTableData(final Table Table, final String data, final boolean isGrey, final TextAlignment textAligned)
{

    final PdfFont helvetica = getPdfFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
    final Text dataText = new Text((data)).setFont(helvetica).setFontSize(7).setItalic()
            .setFontColor(Color.BLACK); // new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 7, Font.ITALIC);
    final Cell cellData = new Cell(1, 1).add(new Paragraph(dataText));
    cellData.setTextAlignment(textAligned);

    if (isGrey)
    {
        cellData.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        cellData.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    cellData.setPadding(0f);
    Table.addCell(cellData);
    return Table;
}

public static void setTableProperties(Table tblName, PdfDocument pdf, int widthSize, int fontSize, String fontStyle, Color fontColor)
{

    tblName.setWidth(pdf.getDefaultPageSize().getWidth() - widthSize); /* Set Width of a Table */
    tblName.setFontColor(fontColor); /* Set Font Color */

    if (fontStyle.toLowerCase() == "italic")
        tblName.setFontSize(fontSize).setItalic();
    else if (fontStyle.toLowerCase() == "bold")
        tblName.setFontSize(fontSize).setBold();
    else if (fontStyle.toLowerCase() == "bold-italic")
        tblName.setFontSize(fontSize).setBold().setItalic();
}

public static PdfFont getPdfFont(final String font)
{
    try
    {
        return PdfFontFactory.createFont(font);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error " + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

1. Why does the word wrap in cell only in certain cases, how do i fix it so it will work (Wrap the text within the column) no matter the text.

   - MATNUMBERUCACHBMPVAIRD4EFANFUC
     (com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer - Element does not fit
     current area)  Why is this, does not work text is not displayed in PDF (and also creates issue below..)
   - MATNUMBERUCACHB-PVAIRD4EFANFUC (Works ok.. it wraps at
     '-')
   - MATNUMBERUCACH1MPVAIRD4EFANFUC (added '1' in middle Works ok, breaks into 2  as 'MATNUMBERUCACH1MPVAIRD4EF' 'ANFUC')
2. Another issue , In code if i call "createTableHeader" method, then at "document.add(myTable)" does not return and goes info a infinite loop and the file keeps growing, no error, exception thrown not sure if there is a way to handle this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Do you mean to say that for "DKJSOCOSISOZLKDOOSOSO" instead of "My Text" the problem occurs?

Comment: I'm afraid this won't help you much but your code (with API changes follow-ups) runs without issue on the current 7.1.x. Actually the whole table generation code was overhauled after 7.0.2, and this was done for a reason, I presume. So I doubt the issue will be fixed in some 7.0.x maintenance release (unless there is a paying customer asking for that). I think, therefore, if you have to keep using 7.0.2, your best bet will be breaking the long "words" before putting them into the table.